# Unable to open more than one A with js click()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, foreach, click, window

How can I open more than one link in a new tab/window in js.

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(item){
    item.click();
    window.open(a.getAttribute('href'), '_blank'); //also does not work
});
```

The only reason I can think why the above doesn't work is for security in chrome?

Comment: We need to see your html and (maybe if defined) the a.click handler.

Comment: What is this `a` tag? Are you sure it should be opened in new tab? It looks to me that you're clicking on first link and then everything stops because new page opens.

Comment: Interesting point, the new tab has opened so it doesn't run any more JS, I was not aware js would stop when it moves tabs. @GiorgioCatenacci this is unimportant other than to say that the `a` does have a href and `_blank`

Comment: Indeed, if it is limited by the browser then ye, its a duplicate.

Comment: I believe so, depending on the target of your anchor tags (`'_blank'` opens new tab) it *should* have similar behavior to `window.open`, and I don't believe that opening a new tab will stop the JS on the page (unless the page redirects instead of opening a new tab)

Comment: Ye, I've never heard of changing tabs stopping js, so much so that I know it doesn't :P. Humm I actually set all elements to have `_blank` before i `click()` but as I say, I have also tried `window.open` and it only opens the first tab

Comment: Also possible typo: `a.getAttribute('href')` -> `item.getAttribute('href')`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about Pop-Up-Blockers getting in your way, you can simply use `window.open()` and open them in new Tabs. You can not make JS **click** multiple links at once because it stops the current tab and focuses the new one (at least with standard settings)

```js
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(function(item) {
  window.open(item.href);
});
```

In Chrome you can block pop-up-blockers by using this script:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(function(item) {
    // will create tabs for every link
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: item.href
    });
});
```

Comment: This also only opened the first link. Also, `chrome.tabs` is undefined

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch to a `for` loop instead. The forEach is returning a reference to a node list, not the object itself. Try the following:

```
function myFunction() {

    var myNodelist = document.querySelectorAll("a");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
        myNodelist[i].click();
    }
 }
```

Comment: This still only opens the first tab sadly.

Comment: Can you create a https://jsbin.com/ link to debug the a demo with HTML

Answer (score 1):

Nailed it, thanks guys for the help.

The first tab opens as chrome is nice, but then the rest are blocked. There is a little icon that says `hey, don't open these pops`

[image]

Click this and you will see all the popups

[image]

Comment: very bad blurring job xD

Comment: Don't forget to accept any answers that helped ;)